# Multiple Installation of Postgresql in Windows 10 and subsystem Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Before I have used windows and git bash, Postgresql (13.1) has been installed.
The path has been added:
[image]
And it worked well.

Later, I have to use Ubuntu (Windows Subsystem), then I use below command to install postgrel in Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

It seems below version has been installed:

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.6 (Ubuntu 12.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
```

But when running in Ubuntu:

```
psql
```

shows error:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory          
Is the server running locally and accepting                           
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Use echo $PATH to check, below two paths have been added:

```
/mnt/c/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/lib:/mnt/c/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/bin
```

What I can see is that Ubuntu has installed Postgrel 12.6, should this path also be added to the system path? In fact, I couldn't figure out where Postgrel 12.6 being added. And this error is really caused by the path or other reason?

Comment: you likely need to start the postgresql server. wsl is a bit different from regular ubuntu & i'm not sure what init system is available to you, but try `sudo service postgresql start`. this _should_ start the server v12.6 since that's installed on linux. since v13 is installed on windows, you have to start the server on windows then connect.

Comment: @HaleemurAli, thank you. After run: sudo service postgresql start, it shows: unrecognize service. Whether it means the server in Ubuntu needs to be installed again or?

Answer (score 0):

Have tried many kinds of methods. In the end, the below trial works:

1. Run as administrator
2. Remove old postgresql

```
sudo apt-get remove postgresql
```

Result:

```
[sudo] password for user:                                   
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                               Building dependency tree                        
Reading state information... Done                              
Package 'postgresql' is not installed, so not removed                                                                                                    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
```

3. update spt

```
sudo apt update
```

Result:

```
Building dependency tree                                    
Reading state information... Done                    
21 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

4. 

```
sudo apt install postgresql postgrsel-contrib
```

Result:

```
Reading package lists... Done             
Building dependency tree                  
Reading state information... Done                          
E: Unable to locate package postgrsel-contrib
```

5. check version

```
psql --version 
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.6 (Ubuntu 12.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
```

6. 

```
sudo service postgrel start 
postgrel: unrecognized service
```

7. 

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-client
```

Result:

```
Success. You can now start the database server using:
pg_ctlcluster 12 main start
```

8. again

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

Now it shows:

```
starting postgresql 12 database (or similar sentence)
```

But no prompt up windows
\q to exit

8. use below to reset password:

```
sudo passwd postgres
```

You will get a  prompt to set password

9. as 'sudo service postgresql start' doesn't work, try below to start postgresql service:

```
su - postgres
```

Now it works:

```
Password:                                                         
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft x86_64)
postgres=#
```

It seems that
step 7 helps to get the server running,
step 8 set the password to postgrel,
step 9 gives another way to start postgres service when sudo command doesn't work.

These are all of my trials. You might skip some steps when you run it.